# How to categorize two array values accordingly

Tags: php, jquery

```
This line of code adds two array values into $carRate variable:

array_push($carRate,array($row['rental_type_value'],$row['rental_by_value']));

public function selectRate()
        {

            $sql="SELECT * FROM rental_by, rental_type WHERE rental_by.rental_type_id=rental_type.rental_type_id";
            $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $carRate=array();

            while($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {
              array_push($carRate,array($row['rental_type_value'],$row['rental_by_value']));
            }
            return $carRate;
        }
```

I call above function in another page like:

```
$setting = new setting();
$selectRate=$setting->selectRate();


$json=array();
array_push($json,array("type"=>$carType,"maker"=>$carMaker,"rate"=>$selectRate));
echo json_encode($json);
```

ANd display in jquery via after fetching data via ajax like this inside success function:

```
if(data && data[0].rate) {   
                        /*for(var c in data[0].maker) {
                            makers += c + ', ';
                        }*/
                         rates +="<table>";
                        $.each(data[0].rate , function( index, value ){
                           console.log(value);                           
                           rates +="<tr><td>"+ value[0] +"</td><td> : </td><td>"+ value[1] +"</td></tr>";
                      });
                       rates +="</table>";
                    }
$('#elementForRates').html(rates && rates.trim().replace(/,$/, "") + "."  || 'No Rate data available');
```

JSON output:

```
["rental_days", "78"]
["rental_days", "56"]
["rental_days", "34"]
["rental_hour", "45"]
["rental_hour", "67"]
["rental_hour", "23"]
["rental_hour", "45"]
["rental_hour", "67"]
```

ANd this outputs like this:

rental_days :   78
rental_days :   56
rental_days :   34
rental_hour :   45
rental_hour :   67
rental_hour :   23
rental_hour :   45
rental_hour :   67

Desired result:

rental_days :   78,56,34
rental_hour :   45,67,23,45,67

Is there a way to categorize/sort the rental_type_value and rental by value in php itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is returned like this:

```
var data = [
    ['rental_days', '78'],
    ['rental_hour', '67'],
    ['rental_days', '56'],
    ['rental_hour', '45'],
    ['rental_days', '34'],
    ['rental_hour', '23'],
    ['rental_hour', '45'],
    ['rental_hour', '67']];
```

You could categorize the data client side:

```
var categorized = {};
data.forEach(function(d){
    if(!!categorized[d[0]]){
        categorized[d[0]].push(d[1]);
    } else {
        categorized[d[0]] = [d[1]];
    }
});
```

And add the rows to the table like this:

```
for (var c in categorized) {
    $('table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + c + '</td><td>' + categorized[c].join() + '</td></tr>');
};
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj8okLsx/)